# Working out percentage of polygon covering another using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, area

I have 2 polygon tables, `polytable_a` and `polytable_b`. `a` has 1000s of features and 100s of unique names (a1, a2, a3, a4.... etc) assigned to the polygons. `b` also has 250,000 features but only 3 unique names (b1, b2, b3).

No features within table `a` overlaps other features in table `a`. The same is the case for table `b`.

I'd like to work out, for each unique poly name in table a, what % of it's own area is covered by the various shapes within table b?

ie:

```
polytable_a name    b1%   b2%   b3%
a1                  40    5     0
a2                  0     20    5
a3                  0     0     5
a4                  0     0     25
```

[image]

bm13563's answer below works great for small poly tables, but the query runs endlessly for these 2 large tables I'm using. I need a solution that will work on 2 tables with 100s of thousands of rows.

Comment: Can any of these polygons *having the same 'name'* (in both tables) overlap?

Comment: @geozelot no overlap within the same table. just bordering along edges.

Answer (score 6):

This should give you the cumulative percentage of every unique combination of your *a_name* and *b_name* in the form a_name | b_name | p_cover:

```
SELECT foo.a_name as aname, bar.b_name as bname, ST_AREA(ST_INTERSECTION(foo.geom, bar.geom)) / ST_AREA(foo.geom) as pcover
FROM (
        SELECT a_name, ST_UNION(geom) as geom
        FROM a
        GROUP BY a_name
     ) as foo, (
        SELECT b_name, ST_UNION(geom) as geom
        FROM b
        GROUP BY b_name
     ) as bar
WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(foo.geom, bar.geom)
```

This groups both tables by the target column and the geometry, resulting in a single geometry for each unique entry. You calculate the percentage area for each combination by doing the sum intersection of *a_name* and *b_name* over *a_name* for each combination of features. You could omit the ST_INTERSECTS to retain all of your *table_a* entries, but this may result in a significant slow-down. Getting the results into the format you described may require some fiddling - it may be possible to do it as part of this query, but would probably be easier to add and update the columns from *table b* to *table a* if there are only 3 columns in *table b*.

Comment: Just to be pedantically correct: `ST_Intersects` will have no effect on execution time whatsoever; first off, it sounds like we can assume all unioned collections of the first table intersects all unioned collections from the second table, but most of all, since you are checking against newly created (unindexed) geometries, both (temporary) tables from the sub-queries will have to get sequentially scanned anyways.

Comment: It might be faster to avoid doing the union, but to compute the individual intersections first and then sum the resultants grouping by name.  It's better to avoid computing larger geometries whenever possible.  (However, If the OP also needed the percentage NOT covered then the union might be required)

Comment: SQL for above idea: `SELECT a.name, b.name, ST_Area(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom))/ST_Area(a,geom) pct 
FROM polytable_a AS a JOIN polytable_b AS b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom); `

Comment: Edit for above, including GROUP BY:  `SELECT a.name, b.name, SUM( ST_Area(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom))/ST_Area(a.geom) ) pct
FROM poly_a a JOIN poly_b b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
GROUP BY a.name, b.name;`

Comment: You might look at `(x.geom && b.geom AND ST_Relate(x.geom, b.geom, 'T********'))` instead of ST_Intersects, if the query planner is not being stimulated to use the geom index.